# Get wikipedia page url by pageId

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I use [wikipedia api](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) to get an extract from a random page.

There is example response:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "grncontinue": "0.701350797294|0.701351244349|4312122|0",
        "continue": "grncontinue||"
    },
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "1485573": {
                "pageid": 1485573,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "some title",
                "extract": "some text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now I know `pageid` of this page.

**How** can I get `url` of this page by `pageid`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can the get the URL by requesting it from the API by adding [`info` property](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Binfo) and `inprop=url`. It can be combined with the [`extracts` property](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts) like this: `prop=info|extracts&inprop=url`.

For example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&grnlimit=2&prop=info|extracts&inprop=url

```
{
"continue": {
    "excontinue": 1,
    "continue": "||info"
},
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "864588": {
            "pageid": 864588,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Benbane Head",
            ...
            "fullurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benbane_Head",
            "editurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Benbane_Head&action=edit",
            "canonicalurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benbane_Head",
            "extract": "<p><span></span></p>\n\n<p><b>Benbane Head</b>, or <b>Benbane</b> (from Irish <i>an Bhinn Bh\u00e1n</i>, meaning \"the white headland\"), is the northernmost point of mainland Northern Ireland. It is in County Antrim, near the Giant's Causeway, which lies between Causeway Head and Benbane Head. The nearest settlements are Bushmills and Portballintrae.</p>\n<h2><span id=\"References\">References</span></h2>\n\n<p><br></p>"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also just use the `pageid` in the URL itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=864588